# How do I efficiently pass an ActiveRecord relation to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails view that makes heavy use of scopes to filter down an Invoice table of hundreds of thousands of rows down to several thousand `@invoices` filtered records. `@invoices` object is an ActiveRecord relation.
Once the user presses a button in the view, these thousands of records need to be sent for processing to another controller / model.

Which would be the best way to accomplish this?

Passing the `@invoices` object as a param is not possible, so I can only think of two options:

1) passing an array of ids as parameters like this:

```
link_to bulk_process_path(@comprobantes.pluck(:id)), method: :post
```

but I'm worried I would hit the server's post max size if there a lot of records

2) passing the scopes involved in the original filtered view as parameters and recreating the filter in the target controller.

However this seems like unnecessary hits on the database. Furthermore, if I ever wanted to implement checkboxes to further refine the filtered view, then this method wouldn't work

3) Creating a temp table in the view, sending the name as a parameter and then reading it from the external controller? Then I'd have to keep track of and delete stale temp tables. Doesn't seem very elegant.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but there doesn't seem to be an elegant solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing with these thousands of records that "need to be sent for processing to another controller / model"?

Comment: I would go with a option 2. I'm not sure what you mean that it wouldn't work if you add checkboxes (you could send the filters AND the checkboxes, why not?).

Comment: Or store them in session if possible, only the IDs. But my preference would be to pass the filters only if the records are too many.

Comment: Hi @MarkMerritt These are internal invoices that are passed to electronic invoicing. I need to pre-process them and send them to an external service.

Comment: Hi @arieljuod. Client has asked to be able to finetune filtered records by manually checking and unchecking checkboxes in the index view, so yes I would have to send this data as well, which pretty much means option 1.

Comment: When you finetune you can optimize that to only send the unchecked ones for example. I was thinking on another option, I'll post an answer.

Comment: If you have several thousand records on a page I think the result is way to overwhelming anyway. It is fine for manipulating batches, but when it comes down to selecting individual records you might want to paginate your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest another option.

When the user enters the page and starts filtering, you can save the filters on the session, then you do ajax requests on each checkbox changes and you can save those ids as exceptions when it's unchecked or remove the exception when it's checked.

You can even use websockets to make it more realtime.

You can also change the session storage method to ActiveRecordStore if you think the exceptions array can be too big, or use something like redis which is really fast.

That way, when the user has finished finteuning the filter, you do a post request but you don't need to send any params, everything is saved on the session. You then can exclude all the ids of unchecked and recreate the filter with the parameters.

Personally I think I would go this way. Hope this helps.